# I have a texture as my background but it causing another texture not to appear in Spritekit?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I have this code as my background as a moving background:

```
    SKTexture* bgTexture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"nightbackground"];
    bgTexture.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;

    SKAction* movebgSprite = [SKAction moveByX:-bgTexture.size.width*2 y:0 duration:0.1 * bgTexture.size.width*2];
    SKAction* resetbgSprite = [SKAction moveByX:bgTexture.size.width*2 y:0 duration:0];
    SKAction* movebgSpritesForever = [SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction sequence:@[movebgSprite, resetbgSprite]]];

    for( int i = 0; i < 2 + self.frame.size.width / ( bgTexture.size.width * 2 ); ++i ) {
        SKSpriteNode* sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:bgTexture];
        sprite.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2);
        [sprite runAction:movebgSpritesForever];
        [self addChild:sprite];
```

And I add this code to have to respawning pipes:

```
SKTexture* _pipeTexture1 = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"Pipe1"];
_pipeTexture1.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;
SKTexture* _pipeTexture2 = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"Pipe2"];
_pipeTexture2.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;

SKNode* pipePair = [SKNode node]; 
pipePair.position = CGPointMake( self.frame.size.width + _pipeTexture1.size.width * 2, 0 );
pipePair.zPosition = -10;

CGFloat y = arc4random() % (NSInteger)( self.frame.size.height / 3 );

SKSpriteNode* pipe1 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:_pipeTexture1]; 
[pipe1 setScale:2]; 
pipe1.position = CGPointMake( 0, y ); 
pipe1.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:pipe1.size];
pipe1.physicsBody.dynamic = NO; [pipePair addChild:pipe1];

SKSpriteNode* pipe2 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:_pipeTexture2];
[pipe2 setScale:2]; 
pipe2.position = CGPointMake( 0, y + pipe1.size.height + kVerticalPipeGap ); 
pipe2.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:pipe2.size];
pipe2.physicsBody.dynamic = NO; [pipePair addChild:pipe2];

SKAction* movePipes = [SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction moveByX:-1 y:0 duration:0.02]];
[pipePair runAction:movePipes];

[self addChild:pipePair];
```

For some reason when I add this code the two pipes dont appear but something does push my character back. It just does not show up. If I remove the background code, the pipes appear and it works again? What is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably this:

```
pipePair.zPosition = -10;
```

When adding your background sprites you don't specify any `zPosition` meaning they'll get the default 0.0 which is visible in front of anything at -10. Your character is pushed back because the physics-bodies are still interacting with each other even if the sprite is covered visually.

```
pipePair.zPosition = 10; // (or any other positive value)
```

ought to fix your problem.

Comment: You're welcome, feel free to up vote and/or tick my answer as accepted if you think it deserves to be... ;-)

Comment: i want set random pipes in landscapemode not working properly give me any idea...